# Как подключить Substance к проекту в IntelleJ IDEA?

Tags: java, swing

Скачал библиотеки с сайта, подключил их через `Project Structure->Libraries`, написал код и выскакивает

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/pushingpixels/trident/ease/TimelineEase, подскажите что делать нужно?(Код ниже)

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
import java.awt.event.WindowListener;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import org.pushingpixels.substance.api.*;
import org.pushingpixels.substance.api.skin.*;

/**
 * Created by Expo1on on 28.07.2014.
 */
public class Redactor  {

    JFrame f=new JFrame();
    static JTabbedPane tp=new JTabbedPane();
    static int i=1;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Redactor r=new Redactor();
        setupLAF();
        r.go();
    }

    public static void setupLAF() {
        try {
            SubstanceLookAndFeel.setSkin(new GraphiteGlassSkin());
            SubstanceLookAndFeel.setSkin("org.pushingpixels.substance.api.skin.GraphiteGlassSkin");
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel(new SubstanceGraphiteGlassLookAndFeel());
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel("org.pushingpixels.substance.api.skin.SubstanceGraphiteGlassLookAndFeel");

        } catch (Exception ex) {}
    }
```

Comment: @Expo1on, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку {} редактора.

Comment: Библиотеку мало подключить в проект, еще нужно добавить зависимость в модуль.

Comment: gcoder, конкретней можно?

Comment: Секция [Adding existing libraries to module dependencies][1].
  [1]: http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/configuring-module-dependencies-and-libraries.html

Comment: gcoder, не помогла, так же ошибка выходит

Comment: Вот [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2892926/java-substance-look-and-feel-problem) аналогичная проблема.